# Is it possible to copy ebooks from a kindle to my desktop?

Tags: ebooks

I have a Kindle with many ebooks on it. I would like to back them up onto my desktop. I have a cable that will go from my Kindle to USB, but I don't know how to do this. Thank you in advance for all of your help.

Comment: Could you please be more specific? What Kindle do you own? From you got the ebook in your Kindle? Are you trying to transfer them to an Ubuntu computer?

Comment: I use Calibre from the repos to manage the books on my Kindle. You might look at it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Kindle Fire does not automount in Ubuntu 12.04. The dmesg tail does not show any usb storage when Kindle is plugged in.  Install package mtp-tools and mtpfs

```
sudo apt-get install mtp-tools mtpfs
```

Make a directory under /mnt named mtp

```
sudo mkdir /mnt/mtp
```

Plug in the kindle and mount it

```
mtpfs /mnt/mtp
```

Your kindle files should now appear under /mnt/mtp
Browse for your books and just copy them off. I forget exactly where they were, maybe under /mnt/mtp/kindle
Unmount the kindle (or command fusermount -u /mnt/mtp )

```
sudo umount /mnt/mtp
```